# Most optimal way to store nested information in a database

Tags: database, postgresql

I want to store some nested information in a Postgres database and I am wondering what is the most optimal way to do so.

I have a list of cars for rent, structured like this:

[Brand] > [Model] > [Individual cars for rent of that brand and model], ex.:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Audi",
    "models": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "A1",
            "cars": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "license": "RPY9973",
                    "mileage": "41053"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "license": "RPY3001",
                    "mileage": "102302"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "license": "RPY9852",
                    "mileage": "10236"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "A3",
            "cars": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "license": "RPY1013",
                    "mileage": "66952"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "license": "RPY3284",
                    "mileage": "215213"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "license": "RPY0126",
                    "mileage": "19632"
                }
            ]
        }
        ...
    ]
}
...
```

]

Currently, having limited experience with databases and storing arrays, I am storing it in a 'brands' table with the following columns:

id (integer) - brand ID
name (text) - brand name
models (text) - contains stringified content of models and cars within them, which are parsed upon reading

In practice, this does the job, however I would like to know what the most efficient way would be.

For example, should I split the single table into three tables: 'brands', 'models' and 'cars' and have the tables reference each other (brands.models would be an array of unique model IDs, which I could use to read data from the 'models' table, and models.cars would be an array of unique car IDs, which I could use to read data from the 'cars' table)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than store it as `json`, `jsonb`, or as arrays, the most efficient way to store the data would be to store it as relational data (excluding the data types for brevity):

```sql
create table brands(
 id,
 name, 
 /* other columns */
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table models(
 id,
 name,
 brand_id REFERENCES brands(id),
/* other columns */
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table cars(
 id,
 model_id REFERENCES models(id),
 mileage, 
 license,
/* other columns */
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

You can then fetch and update each entity individually, without having to parse json.  Partial updates is also much easier when you only have to focus on a single row, rather than worrying about updating arrays or json.  For querying, you would join by the primary keys. For example, to get rental cars available by a brand:

```sql
select b.id, b.name, m.id, m.name, c.id, c.mileage, c.license
 FROM brands b
   LEFT JOIN models m 
   ON m.brand_id = b.id
   LEFT JOIN cars c 
   ON c.model_id = m.id
where b.id = ?
```

Based on querying / filtering patterns, you would then also want to create indexes on commonly used columns...

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_car_model ON cars(model_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_model_brand ON models(brand_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to store the nested data in your postgres database is `json` or `jsonb` field. 
The benefits using `json` or `jsonb` are:

- significantly faster to process, supports indexing (which can be a significant advantage),
- simpler schema designs (replacing entity-attribute-value (EAV) tables with jsonb columns, which can be queried, indexed and joined, allowing for performance improvements up until 1000X)

Comment: How would this be faster than relational storage?